# How to send multipart/form-data and nested json in the same request in postman?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest, postman

I have a REST api that takes data of nested json including multipart file

While testing the REST api through postman I am having problems.

I don't exactly know how to send the diverse types of data that I need - multipart/form-data file and nested json.

I have used REST in each case separately in other projects but I am unable to combine them in one request.

To use multipart/form-data I have to select form-data in the Body, then File from the dropdown in the key field, click on the select files button on the value field and select the file I want to upload.

[image: Adding file in form-data]

To use nested json I have to select raw in the dropdown, and select json at the right of it and simply add the nested json in the body.

[image: adding json data]

But how do I combine these two approaches?

I need multipart/form-data as well as nested json in the same request. How do I send these from postman? I am trying various approaches as you can see in the screenshots but I am not getting anywhere.

Thanks in advance

P.S. If it matters, I am using java (spring boot) for the backend.

Comment: Did you try this? https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3331#issuecomment-399971725

Comment: I created a json file for the second json data (repairStatus) and now I am getting the error **400 Bad Request.** In the console of intellij I get the error **Field error in object 'ticket' on field 'repairStatus': rejected value.....blah ...blah...blah..........no matching editors or conversion strategy found**

Comment: If anyone else is looking for solution, none of the suggested ideas worked for me. But I manage to solve my problem by breaking down the requests into two parts. First I send the multipart file and in the next request I send the nested json part and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach is correct. However to pass the most complicated data it will be a nightmare to do from that location. If passing data from postman is the requirement then you can use the pre-request script in the postman. Below is the example:-

[image]

For pre-req, I have kept a basic js object.
[image]

Try with this feature.

Comment: I tried your approach but I get the error message "status":400, "error": "Bad Request" in postman.
In the intellij console the error is 
Field error in object 'ticket' on field 'repairStatus': ......blah.........blah.......blah..... Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value '{"status":"repaired","remarks":"already repaired","amount":1000}'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException:
I double checked all the data types and they are correct!

Comment: can you attach the pre-req value which you have configured? It seems there is some issue with the object you kept there. it should be in proper form.

Comment: var data = {
    name : 'Manish' ,
    phone: '9383848433',
    invoice: '',
    repairStatus: {
        status: 'repaired',
        remark : 'already repaired',
        amount: 1000
    }
};

pm.variables.set("someData", JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: try with the above one.

Comment: I used your suggestion but still getting the same errors. When defining pre-request variable if I use pm.variables.set(), I get the error **Unresolved Variable
This variable is not defined in the active collection, environment or globals.** while hovering over the variable in postman. The variable is recognized and details shown in hovering only if I use pm.environment.set(). Does this make any difference?  [stackoverflow.png](https://postimg.cc/jnNkK5Kd)

Comment: Can you post the pre-request field snapshot.

Comment: in addition to the pre-request that you posted above, I tried following:
var data = { status: 'repaired', remarks : 'already repaired', amount: 1000 };
pm.environment.set("someData", JSON.stringify(data));
Another variation that I tried:
var status = {
    "status":"repaired",
    "remarks":"already repaired",
    "amount":1000.0
};
pm.environment.set("repairStatus",JSON.stringify(status));
and some more variations.

Comment: You did not get this.  pm.environment.set("repairStatus",JSON.stringify(status)); if you write this then you can't get {{somedata}}. You will get {{repairStatus}}. You use the json which I posted, and keep  pm.environment.set("somedata",JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: I am aware of that and I have adjusted the variables accordingly. When I have used {{someData}} I defined it as someData and when I used {{repairStatus}} I defined it as repairStatus. I was trying different variations and the variables got mixed. But I have always checked that I am using the variable that I have defined.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the above answer and it worked for me.

Step 1: set json data value in pre-request Script.

```
var data = {    
name:"COD Black Ops",
cost:60,
}
pm.variables.set("somedata",JSON.stringify(data));
```

Step 2: set form values.
enable content type option from (...) like button next to description column in order to set the value of your json field as "application/json".

Step 3: express code for handling form data

```
const multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer(<options>)
app.post('/stats', upload.single('uploaded_file'), function (req, res) {
  // req.file is the name of your file in the form above, here 'uploaded_file'
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any 
console.log(req.file, req.body)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

(2023) a simple way after a while !
to send nested json and a file in form-data:

[image]